# Installing AspNetCoreModuleV2 by itself, or making sure it get's installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I'm currently trying to automate the installation procedure of ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle. It is going to be a setup which first starts the Setup of the Bundle which the user has to click through and then enables IIS. Since the application that this setup installs and is later hosted by the IIS, is built as a self-contained app, I couldn't care less about the runtime and whatnot, but I need the AspNetCoreModuleV2 to be installed.

My Problem is, on all my test systems where I tested it, I cannot get it to install the module reliably. Sometimes it get's installed directly, sometimes only after restarting the .NET Core Setup and hitting repair.

This is true for systems that have seen previous installs of the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle, but also system that im fairly certain (but not sure) haven't.

I was looking into cleaning up all references to the module, but after uninstalling the bundle, deleting all the folders, deleting registry entries, and cleaning it from the IIS Config file (yes the uninstallation didn't touch any of these), it seems that the setup still picks it up somewhere and then just doesn't install it.

I really don't want to look around the whole system just to check if the module was installed correctly or not, and I also don't want to double-prompt the user with the installation of the hosting bundle.

Since the module consists of a single file, at least from what I found so far, could I just redistribute the .dll, copy it to where it should be and add the reference to it in the IIS config file by myself?

Or can I get the installer to full-install the hosting package no matter what's on the System?

Comment: "the user has to click through and then enables IIS"? Why? IIS should be installed first, and automation shouldn't involve user click. Also when installation doesn't work well, check the installation log to learn the actual cause.

Comment: Well where can I find the installation log?

Comment: Well, any search engine should lead you to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#module-version-and-hosting-bundle-installer-logs

Comment: Well, that little detail is easily overlooked when in haste. Thank you for pointing those logs out to me. Maybe now I can see what's going on with that setup. Also, I wrote my question in the wrong order from what happens. The way you described it, IIS first, then .NET Core is of course the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the logs that [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) pointed me to, I found a `aspnetcoremodule_x64_en_v2.msi` package, that I can run with msiexec to make totally sure it is installed correctly. And yes, without the user actually clicking something.

Comment: Where did you find the msi package? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Oskar I looked at the logs that the hosting bundle installer writes into `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp`. In there I found said module, its GUID and that it was extracted into the `%PROGRAMDATA%\Package Cache`, the folder having the GUID as the folder name.

Comment: Can you automate that? It sounds like you first manually installed/unpacked the exe and then you could retrive the MSI?

Comment: That's what I did. Installed the newest version of the Hosting Bundle, looked at the logs, find and retrieve the MSI for the module, and pack it into my setup. Don't know where it was in the log file, but you can probably automate that.

Comment: Hopefully the MSI stays the same since the hosting bundles is updated on each NET release (currently at 5.0.5). I used the permalink and downloaded the exe instead. It can be installed non-interactively by using the arg `/passive`.